# Initializing Scala's Option[String] from a string so that certain value leads to None

Tags: scala

Is there a shorter way to doing this:

```
val accessControlAllowOrigin = c_dash.getString("access-control-allow-origin") match {
  case "" => None
  case x => Some(x)
}
```

This is reading in a Typesafe Config value, where empty string denotes the absence of such a config (in Typesafe Config it's good manners to include all values, not leaving anything out).

Is there something like:

```
val sopt = Option( s, "magic" )
```

..which would provide either `Some(s)` or `None` if `s`'s value is `"magic"`?

By looking at the [doc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Option) I came to:

```
scala> def f(s: String) = (Some(s) filter( _ != "magic" ))
f: (s: String)Option[String]

scala> f("aaa")
res1: Option[String] = Some(aaa)

scala> f("magic")
res2: Option[String] = None
```

Is that the simplest?

Comment: I'd expect such post-processing to happen at the config level, but I don't see a hook. (I haven't used it yet.) `withFallback` is closest, but you can't supply a fallback programmatically with a custom config; maybe `ConfigFactory.parseString` is a way for the simple case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `filter`, which works the same for an `Option` as it would for any other collection:

```
c_dash.getString("access-control-allow-origin").filter(_.nonEmpty)
```

Anything not matching the `filter` predicate will become `None`.

Comment: Thanks. I remained using a match since also some other logic creeped into the block. It's often that when there is no obvious ready-made function in Scala, there's a reason for it. So here as well: real cases are more complex than what I was asking for.

Answer (score 2):

I may be missing something obvious, but how about:

```
val sopt = if (s == "magic") None else Some(s)
```

Or, for your f():

```
def f(s:String) = if (s == "magic") None else Some(s)
```

or, more generically:

```
def noneIfDefault(s:String, default: String) = if (s == default) None else Some(s)
```